# ¿Que puedo hacer para hacer que una impresión por pantalla se repita determinado número de veces sin tener que escribir cada una?

Tags: c++, bucles

soy nueva en programación y estoy intentando hacer un programa que lea 10 número y determine cual es el mayor y el menor, y el promedio de los 10 números, pero me piden que para el código debo usar bucles ya sea while, do while o for. Por eso tengo una pregunta ¿cómo podría imprimir lo siguiente 10 veces con bucle?

```
cout << "Ingrese un número: " << endl;
cin << num
```

y también después de que se imprima 10 veces que se pueda tener las variables para poder definir cual es el mayor y el menor y el promedio de todos sus números.

Agradecería mucho que alguien me pueda explicar, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: y probaste usar un bucle?

Comment: sé que necesito un bucle, pero no entiendo como lo tendría que hacer

Comment: que parte no entendes? como funciona un for? como funciona un while? sabes escribirlo? sabes que repite su contenido? ya hiciste otras preguntas y aplicaste bucles, por eso mi duda...

Comment: exactamente, no sé como funciona el for por eso mi duda, sé que lo puede usar para  una sumatoria de numeros pero no entiendo bien como hacerlo en el caso de querer que una acción se repita determinado número de veces y que cada vez se registre en una variable distinta para poder hacer el promedio y definir cual es mayor y menor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pude notar que sos nuevo en la programación como bien comentaste, es por eso que te proveeo con otra solución, en la cual no se deben utilizar vectores(arrays).

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>;



main(){

int numero, total = 0, mayor = 0, menor = 99999, cant=0;
float  promedio;
int i;

for (i=0; i<10; i++){

    cout <<"Ingrese un numero: " << endl;
    cin >>numero;

    cant++;

    if(numero > mayor){

        mayor = numero;
    } else {

        mayor = mayor;

    }


    if(numero < menor){

        menor = numero;
    } else {

        menor = menor;

    }

    total+=numero;

    cout<<cant<<endl;





}


    if(cant > 0){
       promedio = total/cant;
    }

    else{
        cout<<"No se puede calcular el promedio"<<endl;
    }

cout<<"El mayor: "<<mayor<<endl;
cout<<"El menor: "<<menor<<endl;
cout<<"Promedio: "<<promedio<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! así lo he podido entender mucho mejor, enserio me ayudas un montón!!

Answer (score 3):

1. Crea una colección de 10 números:

   ```
   int numeros[10];
   ```
2. Pide los números en un bucle:

   ```
   for (int &numero : numeros)
   {
       cout << "Ingrese un número:\n";
   //                             ^^ <--- El salto de línea en el propio texto.
       cin >> numero;
   //      ^^ <--- Para leer, los ángulos van en la otra dirección.
   }
   ```

Comment: Muchas gracias! me fuiste de gran ayuda